# Laravel 7: unit test set default request header in setUp()

Tags: laravel, testing, global, laravel-7

I want to set my headers for all requests in a test in the setUp method instead of doing it to all the tests separately.

Is there an easy way to do this?

So par example:

```
$this->withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $response['data']['token'],
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ])
```

To:

```
setUp(){
$this->setHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $response['data']['token'],
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Of course. You could create an intermediary parent class `TestCaseWithToken` (or whatever you'd like to name it) that is going to extend the `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` and add your overriden method there

```
protected function setUp(): void 
{
   parent::setUp();
   // set your headers here
   $this->withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->getBearerToken(),
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ]);

}

protected function getBearerToken()
{
   return '';
}
```

Additionally if your token changes in the `$response` variable, you could build a function that returns the token so you could easily override the method in the individual test classes. You could opt for a class property and a setter method, will work the same.

If you want to get the token of the user you want to log in, it can be easily done. Just make the `getBearerToken` method return something like `auth('api')->login($this->authUser);`(this is goint to return the actual token) and set the `$authUser` once per test file. Hope this helps you in the right direction.